# how to dynamically change array in highchart?

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

This is my array of series.

```
var newData = [{
        name: 'All',
        data: myVar,
        grouping: false,
        zIndex: 1,
        color: '#999966',
        stack: 1,
        dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,

                shadow: false,

                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                   if (this.y != 0) return '<div class=\'amount\'>' + this.y + '</div>'; 
                },
                y: 0,

            },
    },{
        name: 'Negative',
        data: mySeries[0],
        grouping: true,
        zIndex: 2,
        color: '#FF3030',
        dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,

                shadow: false,

                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    if (this.y != 0) return '<div class=\'amount\'>' + this.y + '<img src="img/neg.png"></div>'; 
                },
                y: 0
            },
    }, {
        name: 'Positive',
        data: mySeries[1],
        grouping: true,
        zIndex: 2,
        color: '#7ACC29',
        dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,

                shadow: false,

                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    if (this.y != 0) return '<div class=\'amount\'>' + this.y + '<img src="img/pos.png"></div>'; 
                },
                y: 0
            },
    }
    ];
```

In configuration I make pointing to this array.

```
series: newData,
```

Question: How can I dynamically change highchart to point to different array? For example to "oldData".
Make like this:

```
 series: oldData,
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of it, you can use [series.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) / [setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData)

Comment: I was trying setData. But I do really need save properties. And drilldown to another plot and come back to main plot. This array named "newData" is main. And it has a drilldowned data. For example   in myVar. I am drilldowning like this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004614/highcharts-drilldown-from-bar-pie-or-bar-column

Comment: Thank you! I changed it with using setData. But it code is huge. Is it possible to make pattern of properties of each series?

Comment: Should be possible, but in the setData you have only array of points, have you any example of it? I will check it deeper.

Comment: Look at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/h6qa5k6h/2/), Is it possible make these very very bad code to make more better. I hate this goBack function xD